# log étale topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Is it known whether the log étale topology is subcanonical on all, not necessarily fine and saturated, log schemes?

I am interested in the following two possible definitions of log étale between general (i.e. not necessarily fine and saturated) log schemes:

1. Kato's 3.2 and 3.3 (in http://www.math.brown.edu/~abrmovic/LOGGEOM/Kato-log.pdf) with no f.s. conditions;
2. locally of finite presentation and with vanishing Gabber relative cotangent complex.

Comment: What is your definition of log etale topology?

Comment: What sort of morphisms do you allow in covers?  Strict étale?  Kummer étale?

Comment: I have edited the question in order to answer Keerthi and Scott.